# New Joomla Router: Adding additional item type views

Tags: router

I have a requirement to support two different types of views. Example views are like below.

|_ Items 
|__ Item 
|_ Another Items
|__Another Item

So I am registering the views in the router as below.

```
$type1 = new JComponentRouterViewconfiguration('type1');
$type1 ->setKey('id')->setParent($category, 'catid');
$this  ->registerView($item);

$type2 = new JComponentRouterViewconfiguration('type2');
$type2 ->setKey('id');
$this  ->registerView($type2);
```

The first item pages works fine and ID of the item is successfully recognised. But when I go to item2 page, the ID of the item cannot be recognized from the URL. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest you have used `$this->registerView($item);` which would use the current item?  Just a guess.  As a second guess in the second example you do not register setParent.  Again, just a guess.

Comment: I have two different set of items, let's say Articles and User Profiles in the same component. So I am trying to design routing for them. Articles can have category as parent, user profiles do not have any parent. And already using `$this->registerView`